# Add Incremental ID in a table depends other column

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to add in a table a column with ID Incremental, but I want to this ID increments depends the other column.

This is my table

i am new in Mysql . i want to add a column in table with value depending another column value in the same table .for example i have company_table as below :

```
      code  | name        | type |
      ----------------------------
      AAA   | AAAAA       | A    | 
      BBB   | BBBBB       | A    |  
      CCC   | CCCCC       | C    | 
      DDD   | DDDDD       | D    | 
      EEE   | EEEEE       | D    |
```

I Want to add ID incremental for type A. Example

```
  code  | name        | type | ID  |
  ----------------------------------
  AAA   | AAAAA       | A    | 1   |
  BBB   | BBBBB       | A    | 2   |
  CCC   | CCCCC       | C    | NULL| 
  DDD   | DDDDD       | D    | NULL|
  EEE   | EEEEE       | D    | NULL|
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: you want to add a sequence number, not an `auto_increment`

Comment: you need to show the output of `show create table company` (or whatever the real name is) and do and [edit] and paste it

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem does it solve? You can't just come up with solutions if you don't define the problem first.

Comment: Don't worry about storing contiguous, sequential integers

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with variables:

```
select t.*,
       (case when type = 'A' then @rn := @rn + 1 end) as id
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by code;
```

Note:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The `order by` is needed to guarantee the ordering of the rows.  Based on your data, it looks like the first column determines the ordering.

EDIT:

The same basic idea can be used for a column in a table.  If you don't have the column:

```
alter table t add column id int;
```

Then:

```
set @rn := 0;

update t
    set id = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    where type = 'A'
    order by ??;
```

If you care about the ordering of the values, then put the appropriate column in the `order by` clause.  Otherwise, the values will be correct but their ordering indeterminate.

Comment: I want to create column in table